# Mediaplayer Error: start called in state 4

Tags: android, service, media-player

everytime I start my stream, I get two MediaPlayer Errors.

> 01-03 12:04:35.738: D/PlayerActivity(10164): play 
>  01-03
>   12:04:35.742: D/PlayerService(10164): setAudiotStreamType 
>  01-03
>   12:04:35.742: D/PlayerService(10164): setDataSource 
>  01-03
>   12:04:35.742: D/PlayerService(10164): prepareAsync 
>  01-03
>   12:04:35.742: E/MediaPlayer(10164): start called in state 4 
>  01-03
>   12:04:35.742: E/MediaPlayer(10164): error (-38, 0) 
>  01-03
>   12:04:35.742: D/PlayerService(10164): onPrepared 
>  01-03
>   12:04:35.742: D/PlayerService(10164): onCreate Service 
>  01-03
>   12:04:35.750: E/MediaPlayer(10164): Error (-38,0) 
>  01-03
>   12:04:38.261: D/PlayerService(10164): onPrepared

At the Debug Tag "play", I clicked the play button. 
Than my "onCreate" in the MediaPlayer service is called which executes "setAudioStreamTpe", "setDataSource", "prepareAsync", and then onPrepared(myMediaPlayer). 
OnPrepared only executes mp.start(). After that "onPrepared" is logged. And then, at the end of the "onCreate" from my service, "onCreate Service" is logged.

Why are there 2 onPrepared?! With mp.prepare() i got no errors.

The Code:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate() {
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    prepareMediaPlayer();
    onPrepared(mp);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate Service");
}


    public void prepareMediaPlayer()
{
    try {
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        Log.d(TAG, "setAudiotStreamType");
        mp.setDataSource(PlayerActivity.soundUrl); 
        Log.d(TAG, "setDataSource");
        mp.prepareAsync();
        Log.d(TAG, "prepareAsync");

    } 
    catch (IOException e) {}
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {} 
    catch (IllegalStateException e) {}

}


    @Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();
    if (PlayerService.mp.isPlaying() == true){
        notification();
        PlayerActivity.mpState = PlayerActivity.PLAYING;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared");
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not call `onPrepared(mp);` in `onCreate()`, it will be called once the MediaPlayer is ready.

```
public void onCreate() {
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    prepareMediaPlayer();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate Service");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

state 4 means `Mediaplayer` is in preparing state

and we call other actions like

```
Mediaplayer.start() 
Mediaplayer.stop() 
Mediaplayer.pause()
```

or any other thing .

As per your code it is `Onprepared();`

You can see that after calling

```
Mediaplayer.prepare()
```

or

```
Mediaplayer.prepareAsync()
```

you do not need to call

```
Mediaplayer.Onprepared()
```

It will call onPrepares once MediaPlayer is ready 
just remove

```
onPrepared(mp);
```

after

```
prepareMediaPlayer();
```

And you will be good to go